# Installing AMD Graphic card driver messes up login

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

My laptop model is: Dell inspiron 15R
Graphic card: AMD RADEON
Installing driver completes successfully. after rebooting i have issue loging-in.
TTY1-TTY6 are accesible to me but I cannot login.

After I enter the password, "system problem detected" window is displayed and the login screen appears again.

Please help
Thank you in advance

Comment: I there any reason you can't just add a PPA with latest Mesa?

Comment: nope. i am finding it difficult to install. can you guide me?

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) for how to install a PPA, given your graphics doesn't work ATM, skip to the second answer that shows how to do it from a command prompt. You can use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) for latest in-development Mesa. But since this is "in-development", you need to be ready for regressions including non-booting graphics. I'd rather recommend [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) which is latest stable Mesa.

Comment: @Hi-Angel as instructed, i added the ppd of stable Mesa. but what to do ahead. which package do i need to install from this ppa.

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install mesa`, and when it, hopefully successfully, finished, use `reboot` to reboot the system.

Comment: i am getting about 10-15 package list when did sudo apt install mesa.,
mesa-common-dev, mesa-opencl-icd,mesa-utils,mesa-va-drivers, mesa-vdpau-drivers, mesa-vulkan-drivers etc..

Comment: Nice, it's dependencies, just press "yes".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69130/discussion-between-gunnrryy-and-hi-angel).

Comment: even after installing mesa-va-drivers, i still see the lag in videos that render on 1920x1080 resolution. so i believe the gfx-card driver isnt installed or supporting driver is still missing.